# Setting up PostGis on Amazon RDS

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, postgis, amazon-rds

Ok, so I am fairly new to RDS and AWS, but I can't for the life of me, get my database that I created on my laptop, onto amazon RDS, I did move it to my test VPS and also my desktop machine, with no problems at all, here is what I have tried so far..

```
create extension postgis;
create extension fuzzystrmatch;
create extension postgis_tiger_geocoder;
create extension postgis_topology;
alter schema tiger owner to rds_superuser;
alter schema topology owner to rds_superuser;

CREATE FUNCTION exec(text) returns text language plpgsql volatile AS $f$ BEGIN EXECUTE $1; RETURN     $1; END; $f$;
SELECT exec('ALTER TABLE ' || quote_ident(s.nspname) || '.' || quote_ident(s.relname) || ' OWNER TO rds_superuser')
  FROM (
    SELECT nspname, relname
    FROM pg_class c JOIN pg_namespace n ON (c.relnamespace = n.oid) 
    WHERE nspname in ('tiger','topology') AND
    relkind IN ('r','S','v') ORDER BY relkind = 'S')
s;        

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE testgetwork TO luke;
```

Then I connect to the database and try and load my local copy of the new database...

```
luke@l-xps:~$ psql --host=myhost.dns.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com --port=5432 --username=luke --password --dbname=testgetwork < testgetwork.sql 
Password for user luke: 
SET
SET
SET
SET
SET
ERROR:  schema "topology" already exists
ALTER SCHEMA
CREATE EXTENSION
ERROR:  must be owner of extension plpgsql
CREATE EXTENSION
ERROR:  must be owner of extension postgis
CREATE EXTENSION
ERROR:  must be owner of extension postgis_topology

<more output, removed to save space>

ERROR:  permission denied for relation spatial_ref_sys
invalid command \.
 setval 
-------- 
      1
(1 row)

 setval 

<more output, removed to save space>
```

My question is, how can I move on from here? All of the features just seemed to be blocked by a permissions problem, by user luke is part of the rds_superuser group, does anyone who has experience with PostGis and RDS know how I can rectify this?

```
testgetwork=> \du
                                  List of roles
   Role name   |                   Attributes                   |    Member of    
---------------+------------------------------------------------+-----------------
 luke          | Create role, Create DB                         | {rds_superuser}
 rds_superuser | Cannot login                                   | {}
 rdsadmin      | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication | {}
```

Comment: I'm not super familiar with RDS (yet), but from what I've seen it's very keen on enforcing Owner rules. So, who is the owner of `testgetwork` database? Likely `rdsadmin`. Even if not, you'll probably have greater success running your commands as `rdsadmin`. I realize this isn't ideal, but in terms of getting you out of the gate may prove successful.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem here is with the privileges of user `luke` on database `testgetwork`. Please check `luke`'s privileges. This command:

> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE testgetwork TO luke;

should be executed beforehand. Then the session should be reconnected with user `luke` before executing `create extension` commands. Based on the [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.PostgreSQL.CommonDBATasks.PostGIS.html#Appendix.PostgreSQL.CommonDBATasks.PostGIS.Connect), the proper steps would be:

- When you create an AWS RDS instance, RDS creates a user named `postgres` if you've not modified it. The password is what you entered at the time of creation. The user `postgres` (or named otherwise) shouldn't be used for general DBA or application tasks as it has added privileges and you don't want to mess up with your database (by executing a dangerous command in future). Connect to your database using this user.

> psql --host=<rds_host> --port=5432 --username=postgres --password

- Instead, a separate user should be created granting it only the required permissions. I think this is what OP has done. OP has created a user named `luke`.

> CREATE ROLE luke LOGIN PASSWORD 'pass';

- AWS RDS posgtres instance comes with an already created role name `rds_superuser` with restricted superuser access. `luke` should be granted `rds_superuser` privileges.

> GRANT rds_superuser TO gis_admin;

- Create the database. Since database `testgetwork`  is already created, we'll skip this step.
- Grant the `luke` all privileges on the `testgetwork` database.

> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE testgetwork TO luke;

- Exit the session and reconnect with your AWS RDS PostgreSQL instance with user `luke`.

> psql --host=<rds_host> --port=5432 --username=luke --password

Now run all the extension commands:

```
create extension postgis;
create extension fuzzystrmatch;
create extension postgis_tiger_geocoder;
create extension postgis_topology;
alter schema tiger owner to rds_superuser;
alter schema topology owner to rds_superuser;

CREATE FUNCTION exec(text) returns text language plpgsql volatile AS $f$ BEGIN EXECUTE $1; RETURN     $1; END; $f$;
SELECT exec('ALTER TABLE ' || quote_ident(s.nspname) || '.' || quote_ident(s.relname) || ' OWNER TO rds_superuser')
  FROM (
    SELECT nspname, relname
    FROM pg_class c JOIN pg_namespace n ON (c.relnamespace = n.oid) 
    WHERE nspname in ('tiger','topology') AND
    relkind IN ('r','S','v') ORDER BY relkind = 'S')
s;
```